# Visualforce page language based on the OS language

Tags: visualforce, language, locale

Is there a way to use the Custom Lable translations on the Visualforce page for the public sites? I have one user - Site User, which has set the language to English, but in reality, the user visiting this public page doesn't have to be English speaking, but e.g. Spanish. Is there a way how to define the user language, not from the SF User but from the real user locale?

Answer (score 0):

This is a `language` argument for `apex:page`:

> The language used to display labels that have associated translations
>   in Salesforce. This value overrides the language of the user viewing
>   the page. Possible values for this attribute include any language keys
>   for languages supported by Salesforce, for example, "en" or "en-US".

From the [dev docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)